# how to connect nodejs sequelize aws rds mysql database and ec2 instances

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sequelize.js

I'm trying to connect my `EC2` instance and `AWS RDS` `MySQL` database. Ii returns the database not found an error.

How can I fix git fix?

`RDS` database successfully connect with my `MySQL` workbench

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize('*db name*', '***username***', '****pwd*****', {
    host: '*********.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 3306
    logging: console.log,
    maxConcurrentQueries: 100,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl:'Amazon RDS'
    },
    pool: { maxConnections: 5, maxIdleTime: 30},
    language: 'en'
});
}

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

I'm using

- sequelize version ^6.6.4
- Nodejs version 14.15.1

[Screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q6Oa.png)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you share the RDS instances screen-shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q6Oa.png), you are trying to connect to the `DB` using it's DB name.

But there is a little confusion between `AWS RDS` [`DB Instance name`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateDBInstance.html) and [`MySQL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-database.html) default DB name is `mysql`.

So, I'd suggest to use `mysql` instead of `AWS-tvrs` as DB name.

Comment: I created DB in MySQL workbench. Now It works.